# Cannot retrieve single column from database. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to retrieve single column from my table grades.
For that I have used following code in my controller:

```
public function verify($id,$sid)
{

$grade=Grade::all('annual')->whereLoose('id',$id);
return $grade;

}
```

Where, annual is column name. But it is returning empty set of array [].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**all()** takes a list of columns to load from the database. In your case, you're fetching only one column called **annual**, therefore filtering on **id** later on does not return results. Replace your code with the following and it should work:

```
$grade = Grade::all('id', 'annual')->whereLoose('id', $id);
```

Keep in mind that it will return a collection of objects, not a single object.

**NOTE:** you're always loading all **Grade** objects from the database which is not efficient and not necessary. You can simply fetch object with given id with the following code:

```
$grade = Grade::find($id); // fetch all columns
$grade = Grade::find($id, ['id', 'annual']); // fetch only selected columns
```

Comment: Great! It works perfectly and thanks for the note! I'll keep on that!

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using is loading all rows from the `grades` table and filtering them in code. It is better to let your query do the filter work.

For the columns part, you can add the columns you need to the [`first()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_first) function of the query, like so:

```
public function verify($id,$sid)
{
    $grade = Grade::where('id', $id)->first(['annual']);
    return $grade->annual;
}
```